# Not able to login to salesforce help

Tags: help

I'm not able to use sso to log into the help section of salesforce. Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Salesforce displays the following error message:

> We can’t log you in because of an authentication error. For help,
>   contact your Salesforce administrator.

Error Code: Bad_Id

Comment: What are you using for your identity provider?

Comment: I'm using salesforce.

Comment: Hmm - I have a really stupid question:  Are you trying this from a Sandbox?

Comment: @ChristianDeckert have you rectified the error Christian I am facing the exact same error.